# How to make a process high priority (critical)

Tags: c#, process, windows-ce, thread-priority

I have a win CE application which negotiate with an external serial port.

The serial port protocol has some restricted rules. For example:

> If you receive an ANNOUNCE signal, you should send your ACKNOWLEDGE signal up to 3 milliseconds after that otherwise you failed the negotiation!

So I need to my running process (and though running listening thread) to be ran in a high priority mode. I think the OS should delay/postpone ALL uncritical tasks (it includes all form's painting, repainting, updating, etc.). At result the UI maybe not responsive in some times but it is not important.

I want to know if there is a way/workaround to achieve this goal or not.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Smart Device Framework.

http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/

There is a OpenNETCF.ThreadEntry.SetPriority() method.

Comment: I didn't see that previously. Are you sure It does what I want? I should check and test it before marking it as answer :-) anyway thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to give priority to your process using the compact framework?